# Any progress with DWS and FreePascal?

Tags: dwscript

Trying to compile DWS with FreePascal@Linux, and nearly finished with FPC 3.2.2 - but after update to latest trunc version of 3.3.1 got problems again. Maybe someone had already solved ?

First, found a lot of incomplete code for datetime operations, string comparison, file IO. Well, FPC got broken almost all the compatibility. Seems that last update of DWS had fixed problems in dwsStack module (negative index for function result cause AV)

Script code is:
if SomeStringValue1 <> SomeStringValue2 then Code1;

Let's assume SomeStringValue1 and SomeStringValue2 are empty strings. Somehow Code1 got executed
I checked that TRelNotEqualStringExpr evaluation is False.
Also I changed that to:
if SomeStringValue1 <> SomeStringValue2 then Code1 else Code2;

And really Code2 is executed, but after that Code1 still run !

Any ideas to solve the problem ?

Comment: Well, the problem is a bit deeper and is related to TTightList structure. Seems that latest changes in FreePascal had broken the array memory structure, and old "tricks" are no more working